# Unable to instantiate application java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android

I am trying to run my app in device or emulator. But it's not even allowing to open the main activity. After installing, it throws this exception. I have checked almost every solution that are present on StackOverflow, but none of them is working. 
Efforts that I have made:

1. Tried to run by removing application name from Manifest.xml
2. Changed the Activity name with . as well as with the full path
3. Made lots of changes in build path order and export.

I guess I have tried most of the solutions that are available on StackOverflow. 
Here is my Manifest.xml file

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

```
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@drawable/android_bg"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/ccsecure" />
            <data android:mimeType="document/ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*..*.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*..*..*.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*..*..*..*.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*..*..*..*..*.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*..*..*..*..*..*.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*..*..*..*..*..*..*.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*..*..*..*..*..*..*..*.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*..*..*..*..*..*..*..*..*.ccsecure" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/ccsecure" />
            <data android:mimeType="document/ccsecure" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*..*.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*..*..*.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*..*..*..*.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*..*..*..*..*.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*..*..*..*..*..*.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*..*..*..*..*..*..*.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*..*..*..*..*..*..*..*.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*..*..*..*..*..*..*..*..*.ccsecure" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/ccsecure" />
            <data android:mimeType="document/ccsecure" />
            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*..*.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*..*..*.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*..*..*..*.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*..*..*..*..*.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*..*..*..*..*..*.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*..*..*..*..*..*..*.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*..*..*..*..*..*..*..*.ccsecure" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*..*..*..*..*..*..*..*..*.ccsecure" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

The most surprising thing for me is app is already uploaded by another developer on play store and it's working as expected if I download it from play store. But, it's not allowing me to open the MainActivity after downloading.

Thank you in advance. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Below is the error log from my logcat:

```
06-24 14:45:13.498: E/AndroidRuntime(19619): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 14:45:13.498: E/AndroidRuntime(19619): Process: com.cipher.Shield, PID: 19619
06-24 14:45:13.498: E/AndroidRuntime(19619): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.cipher.Shield/com.cipher.Shield.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.cipher.Shield.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.cipher.Shield-10.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.cipher.Shield-10, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
06-24 14:45:13.498: E/AndroidRuntime(19619):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
06-24 14:45:13.498: E/AndroidRuntime(19619):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495)
06-24 14:45:13.498: E/AndroidRuntime(19619):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170)
06-24 14:45:13.498: E/AndroidRuntime(19619):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304)
06-24 14:45:13.498: E/AndroidRuntime(19619):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-24 14:45:13.498: E/AndroidRuntime(19619):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
06-24 14:45:13.498: E/AndroidRuntime(19619):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
06-24 14:45:13.498: E/AndroidRuntime(19619):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 14:45:13.498: E/AndroidRuntime(19619):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-24 14:45:13.498: E/AndroidRuntime(19619):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
06-24 14:45:13.498: E/AndroidRuntime(19619):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
06-24 14:45:13.498: E/AndroidRuntime(19619):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-24 14:45:13.498: E/AndroidRuntime(19619): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.cipher.Shield.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.cipher.Shield-10.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.cipher.Shield-10, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

Comment: What the error? Attach full crash log.

Comment: can you please add the top part of the manifest as well

Comment: @Nader I have added the upper portion of manifest file

Comment: @SergeyShustikov I have edited with erroe log

Comment: Where `package = ` line? Like an `package="com.cipher.Shield"` ?

Comment: com.cipher.Shield.MainActivity is this the right package path of main activity ?

Comment: @SergeyShustikov this Stackoverflow is not allowing me to paste entire xml file. in my manifest file, it has the package line.

Comment: Did you try to clean delete bin folder and rebuild ?

Comment: @SergeyShustikov   . <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.cipher.Shield"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" >

Comment: @Nader com.cipher.Shield is the package and MainActivity is the activity, I also tried to run clean and rebuild

Comment: What the tool you using to build?

Comment: @SergeyShustikov I am using eclipse

Comment: @SergeyShustikov No I don't have gradle

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse does not include support libraries (i suppose you are using them) into `dex` file. So.

> To fix this, right-click your project, properties, build path and go to export tab. There make sure "Android private libraries" are checked. A clean and rebuild should put you on track ...

And make sure you doesn't included both `support-v4` and `support-v7`. It will make a conflict.

Comment: It is already checked. And after your comment, I tried it once again. Still it is giving the same error.

Comment: @Rushi check also proguard file. It may shrink this class in build process.

Comment: I don't have any idea about proguard file but in my project, there are two proguard files :    1. proguard-project.txt and proguard.cfg. let me know which file to check and what to check in that file.